# Tree implementations in Smalltalk

Tags: tree, smalltalk, squeak, pharo, visualworks

I'm trying to find open-source implementations of Trees (not binary) like Red-black, B-Trees, 2-3 Trees, or General Tree, ideally for Squeak/Pharo, but any other implementations in other Smalltalk flavor will be fine too. I've seen SqueakSource but there are too many binary trees packages and most of them seems to belong to students projects.
Do you know tree implementations?

Comment: Gah! You ask a month or two too soon: I'm about to leverage my unification library to implement red-black and finger trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In http://www.squeaksource.com/BTree.html you find a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) implementation that is extensively used in many commercial applications.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, that implementation is suited or optimized for disk-based retrieval? My data set is relatively small to fit into object memory, however I will give it a try (I did not understood the tests)

Comment: The BTree package in http://www.squeaksource.com/BTree.html is purely for in-memory use. However, based on this code many specialized implementations for disc-based persistency in OODBs have been created: OmniBase (http://www.squeaksource.com/OmniSupport.html), GOODS (http://www.squeaksource.com/GOODS.html), and I think also for GemStone/S and Magma.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated [BTree](https://github.com/sebastianconcept/BTree) for Pharo that I usually use for [Mapless](https://github.com/sebastianconcept/Mapless) based apps.

In that BTree repo, along the `BTree`, you will find a `TSTree` implementation.

And as a Plus a `TreeSet` that was implemented using a `BTree` as support.

Then you have [OmniBase](https://github.com/sebastianconcept/OmniBase) which is a full file-based OODB that includes its own `BTree` implementation.